# How to optimize rendering of thousands rows of data in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently using HTML Table element and styled using blueprintjs. I want to pass thousands rows of data to the table. I know it is crazy and some have suggested in using windowing like `react-window` or pagination. But the problem is that, I want to be able to filter through the whole data, so I'll need the data to be present in the client side instead of paginating it from the database so that I can do `.filter()` live. Any recommendation on how I can render all of the data while also keeping up the performance?

Comment: You could still filter the whole data on the frontend without displaying everything in a table.

Comment: I  am not sure but maybe you can use infinite scroll

Comment: @Weedoze Does that mean I still fetch the whole data to client side, but passed only  a portion of the data into the table?

Comment: @Owenn Ideally you would filter the data when calling the backend to avoid slow loading. If you get all the data at once, you can show them in a table with pagination and you can filter the whole dataset (not only the page you are viewing). Here is an example found on internet: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-application-br83v

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `indexedDb` and storing all data in to it, and like any database you can search and find any record, for getting data and storing them to `indexedDb` you can get data by pagination from server and after each request that returns part of your whole data try to save it in to database until all data received.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing your render,first you should know which affect the performance,it is the computation of the data,or it is the render of the page;

if it is the computation,you can use web worker or webAssembly to speed your computation;

if it is the render, you can consider use a package like:ag-grid ,or you can only render the part of the table in the view,and when scroll the view ,you can set other data to render in the table.

Because this is a advice, no code for you to use immediately,hope it can help you,